# Nuxt.js internal server error when navigating from direct link

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

```
enter code here
```

```js
export default {
    // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
    head: {
        title: 'myApp',
        htmlAttrs: {
            lang: 'en'
        },
        meta: [
            { charset: 'utf-8' },
            { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
            { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
        ],
        link: [
            { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
        ]
    },

    // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
    css: ['~/assets/css/transition.css'],
    pageTransition: "fade",
    // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
    plugins: [
        {src:'~/plugins/axios'},
        { src: '~/plugins/vue-fbauth.js', ssr: false },
        { src: '~/plugins/vue-google', ssr: false },
        { src: "~/plugins/vue2-editor", ssr: false },
        { src: "~/plugins/slider", ssr: false },
        { src: "~/plugins/star-rating", ssr: false },
        { src: "~/plugins/mask", ssr: false },
        { src: "~/plugins/imageUpload", ssr: false },
        { src: "~/plugins/fileUpload", ssr: false },
        { src: "~/plugins/rangeSlider", ssr: false }
    ],


    // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
    components: true,

    // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
    buildModules: [
        ['@nuxtjs/google-analytics', {
            id: 'UA-198003695-1'
        }]
    ],

    // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
    modules: [
        // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/bootstrap
        'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
        '@nuxtjs/axios',
        '@nuxtjs/auth-next', ['nuxt-lazy-load', {
            defaultImage: '/spin2.gif'
        }],
        'nuxt-moment',
        '@nuxt/http'
    ],


    axios: {
        baseURL: 'https://example.com/api/book.', // Used as fallback if no runtime config is provided
    },

    loading: {
        color: '#F48245',
        height: '4px'
    },

    target: 'server',

    // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
    build: {},

    router: { middleware: ['checkUserAuth'] },


}
```

```html
//htaccess

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-domain.com.br$
RewriteRule "(.*.(jpg|gif|png|svg|js|css|woff2))$" "http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1" [P,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) "http://127.0.0.1:3000/$2" [P,L]
```

I have some problems when I use nuxt.js with SSR, my web application works perfect in development mode, but in production mode, I have some unexpected errors,  Errors occur when pages are linked directly, for SSR I am using Nuxt with `asyncData` and I get the following kind of error.

[image]

My application runs to domain **https://www.example.com/** and Backend API is **https://www.api.example.com/api/book**. What is happening, where is the problem.

**I have two questions**

1. Could the reason be the difference between the domains?
2. How can I avoid page crashes on Internal server error if I am using nuxt Axios module?

Comment: Hi, we will need far more debugging details to solve this one. Can you tell us where is your app hosted, edit your question with the content of your `nuxt.config.js` file and also look to see if you are able to successfully build the app locally (not by using `yarn dev` but either `yarn build` or `yarn generate`, depending of your `target` value).

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question, I am able to build my application loccaly using `npm run build` and then serve using `npm run start`

Comment: Where is your code hosted? When is call done? One thing to know, is that `asyncData` is **only** done during page transitions (when moving with `<nuxt-link>`), it is not called when you type your website's location in the URL during the initial render. `fetch()` hook can help with that.

Comment: @kissu, I have tried nuxt fetch, but it also had some problems, it needed to be refresh several times to display the data.

Comment: P.S i have updated my question and add my htaccess file

Comment: Where is your code hosted? Personal VPS? Did you tried this on a simpler platform like Heroku?

Comment: @kissu no it's not VPS, it's dedicated server and we can't configure it :/

Comment: Could hosting be the cause of these problems?

Comment: Where is your code hosted? Did you tried this on a simpler platform like Heroku? This is totally a hosting configuration issue yeah.

Comment: last one, what about different domeins? Could there be a problem with this? thanks for your help!